# MVC Master Page Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a master page that needs to display some data from my database. As an example, I have a header in the page that will display the number of messages / alerts that a user has. Every single controller is going to need to pass this data to the View. What is the best way to do this in an MVC application. I obviously don't want to copy the code in every controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Darin's answer is an `ActionFilterAttribute`, that plunks the data into every Action's ViewData. Where you place the attribute defines which actions get this. Placing it at a root Controller class means all actions will get it.

Comment: I think I will try this method opposed to trying the Child Actions. I don't like the Model Factory solution because I don't think every model should have to inherit from a base model class.

Answer (score 3):

You could use child actions. Phil Haack does a great job explaining them in this [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). This way you would have a specific controller for fetching the data from the repository and passing it to its own partial view. Then in your master page you would simply include the action:

```
<%= Html.Action("index", "somecontroller") %>
```

This way other controllers don't need to pass the data to the view. It has a completely separate lifecycle.

Comment: maybe for clarity: `<%= Html.Action("GetMessages", "MessagesController") %>` and `<%= Html.Action("GetAlerts", "AlertsController") %>`

Comment: Child actions do have their downsides. They force views to be too aware of what is going on. They are also kind of expensive because the system has to simulate an entire second request. Rails used to have similar functionality but it was ultimately removed.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a model that all models inherit from:

```
public abstract class MasterModel
{
    public int NumberOfMessages { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And then you could have some sort of model factory that will create the requested model:

```
public class ModelFactory : IModelFactory
{

    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public ModelFactory(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
         // Inject a repository .. or a service...
         this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public T Create<T>() where T : MasterModel, new()
    {
        var m = new T()
        {
            NumberOfMessages = this.userRepository.GetNumberMessages(currentUser) // Get current user somehow... HttpContext
        };
        return m;

    }
}
```

So then you'd inject IModelFactory into your controller and then use it inside the action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult DoSomething()
{
    var model = this.modelFactory.Create<MyActionModel>();
    return View(model);
}
```

Then your master has `MasterModel` model type and then can use this information. This way all your logic could be kept inside a service/repository that is injected into the factory that creates each view's model. This is what I do and it works out great.